# -bash Terminal error setting up heroku

Tags: unix, heroku, terminal

Trying to setup Heroku according to [this](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/osx) start guide, but Im experiencing a `no such file or directory`.   What is leading to this?   My experience with this `-bash` error is that it it can be to an erroneous space, or character, or obviously that there is no file, but what am I missing?

here is the console error from the setup:

```
localhost:local cf$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: heroku@mydomain.org
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Found existing public key: /Users/cf/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /Users/cf/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: heroku@mydomain.org
Password (typing will be hidden): 
Authentication successful.
localhost:local cf$ cd ~/myapp
-bash: cd: /Users/cf/myapp: No such file or directory
```

The help guide shows

```
Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? [Yn]
Generating new SSH public key.
Uploading ssh public key /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

whereas I already had an SSH key:

```
Found existing public key: /Users/cf/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /Users/cf/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
```

Is that something that need to be looked into? I have also tried in a different instance of the terminal, and that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should create a folder called `myapp`. Before:

```
localhost:local cf$ cd ~/myapp
```

write:

```
localhost:local cf$ mkdir ~/myapp
localhost:local cf$ cd ~/myapp
```

This is not an Heroku issue. You need minimal Unix familiarity ... . Cheer up!

The `~` symbol means 'your home directory'.